# UISwitch requires OFF then ON click (or vice versa) for it to "save" the value and work

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have 2 view controllers...Game Settings View Controller (contains the UISwitch) & Game View Controller. By default, the state of the switch is ON (set in storyboard). The switch's functionality is to set the object to go upward or downward.

Steps:
1. When I first load the game, switch is ON, I play the game and the object correctly moves based on the switch setting being ON (upward in this case).
2. I close and reopen the game, switch is ON, I switch it to OFF, I play the game and the object correctly moves based on the switch setting (downward in this case).
[BUG] - 3. I close and reopen the app, switch is back to ON (because that's the default), I play the game and the object doesn't correctly move based on the switch setting.  It should be going upward because the switch is ON.
[WORKAROUND] - I have to turn the switch OFF and then back ON for it to work.

Here are my 2 view controllers:

**GameSettingsViewController:**

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISwitch *UISwitchInvertGravity;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)SwitchGravity {

    NSUserDefaults *GravitySwitchValue = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [GravitySwitchValue setBool:self.UISwitchInvertGravity.on forKey:@"SwitchOn"];
    [GravitySwitchValue synchronize];
```

**GameViewController**

.m

```
-(void)ObjectMoving {

    NSUserDefaults *GravitySwitchValue = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL SwitchOn = [GravitySwitchValue boolForKey:@"SwitchOn"];

    if (SwitchOn) {

        object.center = CGPointMake(object.center.x, object.center.y + objectFlight);
        objectFlight = objectFlight - 5;
        if (objectFlight < -15) {
            objectFlight = -15;
        }
    }
    else {

        object.center = CGPointMake(object.center.x, object.center.y - objectFlight);
        objectFlight = objectFlight - 5;
        if (objectFlight < -15) {
            objectFlight = -15;
        }
    }

    if (objectFlight > 0) {
        object.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"object-down.png"];
        }
    if (objectFlight < 0) {
        object.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"object-up.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm need some clarification, why are you saving to user defaults if you don't want the value to be persisted?

Comment: I'm a bit new to objective-c, so my clarification will likely lead to your suggested rewrite;) When I had everything in 1 view, it all worked (without nsuserdefault). After breaking it into 2 views and researching, I kept reading about nsuserdefault and thought this was a way to save and retrieve your switch settings in another view. My confusion was how to make my switch setting be reflected in a separate VC. I would also like the last switch setting to persist after closing and reopening the app.

Comment: All MethodNames should be dromedarCase (that means first letter is not capitalized). Same with properties and variables. Only ClassNames should be CamelCase.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'll def clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do:

1 Set the "SwitchOn" in userdefault to yes (this function just **run once** when you **first launch** the app.)in app delegate.

2 Set the UISwitch's value to be the same as "SwitchOn" userdefault value when you go into (load) the viewcontroller which contains that UISwitch.

Comment: This worked, thanks! **In AppDelegate, I added:** 
NSUserDefaults *GravitySwitchValue = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![GravitySwitchValue objectForKey:@"SwitchOn"]) {
        [GravitySwitchValue setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchOn"];
    } 

**And in the GameSettingsViewController, I added:**

_UISwitchInvertGravity.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchOn"];

Answer (score 0):

I could answer it better if I know exactly what is the desired effect. Still, here is my guess.

Setting the visual default of a UISwitch **does not** automatically update your stored *NSDefault "SwitchOn"* value to *YES/NO* boolean.

So here are your options:

1. When your app opens: update the UISwitch value to the stored NSDefault value, if any.
2. OR, when your app opens: update the NSDefault value back to desired default value.

If you take option 2, I would strongly recommend that you simply remove this NSDefault logic if you're not using it anywhere because it'll be basically useless in that case.